# Using magento product model in footer

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to display the Swatch attributes of all the associated simple products to the configurable product that the user is viewing.

I need to do this in the footer which is proving more difficult than I thought as a lot of methods etc are not available in the footer.

I have this code which just shows the Swatch attribute for the configurable product, I need this modified to show the Swatch attribute for all the simple products associated to this configurable.

```
<?php
    $SKU = "2726578";
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$SKU);
    echo $product->getSwatch();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sku = "2726578";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){  
    $childs = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();  
}
```

Hope this helps! Just iterate over the childs and fetch the values.

cheers!

Comment: Worked perfect thanks, `if($_product->getTypeId()` needs to be `if($product->getTypeId()`